# Creating a syntax for the in-program functionality

Tags: java, syntax, syntax-highlighting

In Java, I'm trying to make a program that has a input text area which will react to some syntax defined priorly by me. It should highlight whenever I write the keyword among other words and should do whatever I commanded for.

My question is how to create such syntax? How to make program react to those words? Where to keep those keywords(in an array?)?

Thank you

Comment: When you mentioned input text area, will you be good with a javascript solution rather than java?

Comment: @AnindaBhattacharyya sorry i forgot to mention that it **must** be java desktop based program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well using [TextDemo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) as a starting point here is a naive solution using [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)

The gist is on this function:

```
public void search() {
    hilit.removeAllHighlights();
    for (String s : keywords) {
        String content = textArea.getText();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b"+s+"\\b");

        Matcher m = p.matcher(content);
        while (m.find()) {
            int index = m.start();
            int end = index + s.length();
            try {
                hilit.addHighlight(index, end, painter);
            } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
            }

        }
    }

}
```

The keywords I set up on an array

```
private final String[] keywords = {"public", "final", "static"};
```

And then call `search` within the `DocumentListener` functions:

```
 @Override
 public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent ev) {
    search();
 }

 @Override
 public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent ev) {
    search();
 }
```

Complete Code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.*;

public class HighLightDemo extends JFrame implements DocumentListener {

    private final String[] keywords = {"public", "final", "static"};
    private JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private JTextArea textArea;

    final static Color HILIT_COLOR = Color.GREEN;
    final Highlighter hilit;
    final Highlighter.HighlightPainter painter;

    public HighLightDemo() {
        initComponents();
        hilit = new DefaultHighlighter();
        painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(HILIT_COLOR);
        textArea.setHighlighter(hilit);
        textArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("HighlightDemo");

        textArea.setColumns(20);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setRows(5);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(textArea);

        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);

        //Create a parallel group for the horizontal axis
        ParallelGroup hGroup = layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING);

        //Create a sequential and a parallel groups
        SequentialGroup h1 = layout.createSequentialGroup();
        ParallelGroup h2 = layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING);

        //Add a container gap to the sequential group h1
        h1.addContainerGap();

        //Add a scroll pane and a label to the parallel group h2
        h2.addComponent(jScrollPane1, GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 450, Short.MAX_VALUE);
        h1.addGroup(h2);

        h1.addContainerGap();

        //Add the group h1 to the hGroup
        hGroup.addGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, h1);
        //Create the horizontal group
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(hGroup);

        //Create a parallel group for the vertical axis
        ParallelGroup vGroup = layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING);
        //Create a sequential group v1
        SequentialGroup v1 = layout.createSequentialGroup();
        //Add a container gap to the sequential group v1
        v1.addContainerGap();
        //Create a parallel group v2
        ParallelGroup v2 = layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE);

        //Add the group v2 tp the group v1
        v1.addGroup(v2);
        v1.addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED);
        v1.addComponent(jScrollPane1, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 233, Short.MAX_VALUE);
        v1.addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED);
        v1.addContainerGap();

        //Add the group v1 to the group vGroup
        vGroup.addGroup(v1);
        //Create the vertical group
        layout.setVerticalGroup(vGroup);
        pack();
    }

    public void search() {
        hilit.removeAllHighlights();


        for (String s : keywords) {
            String content = textArea.getText();
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b"+s+"\\b");

            Matcher m = p.matcher(content);
            while (m.find()) {
                int index = m.start();
                int end = index + s.length();
                try {
                    hilit.addHighlight(index, end, painter);
                } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                }

            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent ev) {
        search();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent ev) {
        search();
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent ev) {
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new HighLightDemo().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Okay that is great thank you for your effort ! :) however, I want to define my *own* keywords and functionality to them such as **draw** keyword and should call the method called draw or something. Additionally, there will be many others similar to this. What if I had thousand keywords and another thousand of words that should have only the functionality yet no highlighting, how to keep them? still in string array? Wouldn't it slow down my program for each word searching? Is there any alternative and efficient way of storing and using them ?

Comment: Perhaps you are better off keeping track of `last typed letters` until you find either a break (a space, a delete and ctrl key, etc.) or a `keyword` then call the appropriate function for it. My answer is a naive approach of SEARCHING all in all..  The keywords can be on a Map for faster search.